# How to create a HTML table with a multi-dimensional array with SMARTY?

Tags: php, html, arrays, smarty

See bottom to view most recent code...

Where I'm struggling most is dealing with this specific type of array. See below. Displayed using `var_dump` in PHP. Below you'll see 3 sets of values. I want to be able to create three columns with this data. The values then fill up the rows.

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(28) { [0]=> string(4) "2160" [1]=> string(5) "63800" [2]=> string(6) "175820" [3]=> string(6) "234823" [4]=> string(6) "253080" [5]=> string(6) "256680" [6]=> string(6) "258760" [7]=> string(6) "258840" [8]=> string(6) "259560" [9]=> string(6) "258480" [10]=> string(6) "258550" [11]=> string(6) "258660" [12]=> string(6) "258480" [13]=> string(6) "258300" [14]=> string(6) "256140" [15]=> string(6) "257770" [16]=> string(6) "255960" [17]=> string(6) "255780" [18]=> string(6) "252520" [19]=> string(6) "253980" [20]=> string(6) "252540" [21]=> string(6) "250560" [22]=> string(6) "245700" [23]=> string(6) "253080" [24]=> string(6) "248580" [25]=> string(6) "248860" [26]=> string(6) "249660" [27]=> string(6) "246780" } [1]=> array(34) { [0]=> array(28) { [0]=> string(4) "2160" [1]=> string(5) "63800" [2]=> string(6) "175820" [3]=> string(6) "234823" [4]=> string(6) "253080" [5]=> string(6) "256680" [6]=> string(6) "258760" [7]=> string(6) "258840" [8]=> string(6) "259560" [9]=> string(6) "258480" [10]=> string(6) "258550" [11]=> string(6) "258660" [12]=> string(6) "258480" [13]=> string(6) "258300" [14]=> string(6) "256140" [15]=> string(6) "257770" [16]=> string(6) "255960" [17]=> string(6) "255780" [18]=> string(6) "252520" [19]=> string(6) "253980" [20]=> string(6) "252540" [21]=> string(6) "250560" [22]=> string(6) "245700" [23]=> string(6) "253080" [24]=> string(6) "248580" [25]=> string(6) "248860" [26]=> string(6) "249660" [27]=> string(6) "246780" } [1]=> string(4) "2160" [2]=> string(5) "63800" [3]=> string(6) "175820" [4]=> string(6) "234823" [5]=> string(6) "253080" [6]=> string(6) "256680" [7]=> string(6) "258760" [8]=> string(6) "258840" [9]=> string(6) "259560" [10]=> string(6) "258480" [11]=> string(6) "258550" [12]=> string(6) "258660" [13]=> string(6) "258480" [14]=> string(6) "258300" [15]=> string(6) "256140" [16]=> string(6) "257770" [17]=> string(6) "255960" [18]=> string(6) "255780" [19]=> string(6) "252520" [20]=> string(6) "253980" [21]=> string(6) "252540" [22]=> string(6) "250560" [23]=> string(6) "245700" [24]=> string(6) "253080" [25]=> string(6) "248580" [26]=> string(6) "248860" [27]=> string(6) "249660" [28]=> string(6) "246780" [29]=> string(4) "2150" [30]=> string(5) "63800" [31]=> string(6) "175420" [32]=> string(6) "234843" [33]=> string(6) "253080" } [2]=> array(41) { 

[0]=> array(28) { [0]=> string(4) "2160" [1]=> string(5) "63800" [2]=> string(6) "175820" [3]=> string(6) "234823" [4]=> string(6) "253080" [5]=> string(6) "256680" [6]=> string(6) "258760" [7]=> string(6) "258840" [8]=> string(6) "259560" [9]=> string(6) "258480" [10]=> string(6) "258550" [11]=> string(6) "258660" [12]=> string(6) "258480" [13]=> string(6) "258300" [14]=> string(6) "256140" [15]=> string(6) "257770" [16]=> string(6) "255960" [17]=> string(6) "255780" [18]=> string(6) "252520" [19]=> string(6) "253980" [20]=> string(6) "252540" [21]=> string(6) "250560" [22]=> string(6) "245700" [23]=> string(6) "253080" [24]=> string(6) "248580" [25]=> string(6) "248860" [26]=> string(6) "249660" [27]=> string(6) "246780" } 

[1]=> array(34) { [0]=> array(28) { [0]=> string(4) "2160" [1]=> string(5) "63800" [2]=> string(6) "175820" [3]=> string(6) "234823" [4]=> string(6) "253080" [5]=> string(6) "256680" [6]=> string(6) "258760" [7]=> string(6) "258840" [8]=> string(6) "259560" [9]=> string(6) "258480" [10]=> string(6) "258550" [11]=> string(6) "258660" [12]=> string(6) "258480" [13]=> string(6) "258300" [14]=> string(6) "256140" [15]=> string(6) "257770" [16]=> string(6) "255960" [17]=> string(6) "255780" [18]=> string(6) "252520" [19]=> string(6) "253980" [20]=> string(6) "252540" [21]=> string(6) "250560" [22]=> string(6) "245700" [23]=> string(6) "253080" [24]=> string(6) "248580" [25]=> string(6) "248860" [26]=> string(6) "249660" [27]=> string(6) "246780" } [1]=> string(4) "2160" [2]=> string(5) "63800" [3]=> string(6) "175820" [4]=> string(6) "234823" [5]=> string(6) "253080" [6]=> string(6) "256680" [7]=> string(6) "258760" [8]=> string(6) "258840" [9]=> string(6) "259560" [10]=> string(6) "258480" [11]=> string(6) "258550" [12]=> string(6) "258660" [13]=> string(6) "258480" [14]=> string(6) "258300" [15]=> string(6) "256140" [16]=> string(6) "257770" [17]=> string(6) "255960" [18]=> string(6) "255780" [19]=> string(6) "252520" [20]=> string(6) "253980" [21]=> string(6) "252540" [22]=> string(6) "250560" [23]=> string(6) "245700" [24]=> string(6) "253080" [25]=> string(6) "248580" [26]=> string(6) "248860" [27]=> string(6) "249660" [28]=> string(6) "246780" [29]=> string(4) "2150" [30]=> string(5) "63800" [31]=> string(6) "175420" [32]=> string(6) "234843" [33]=> string(6) "253080" } [2]=> string(4) "2160" [3]=> string(5) "63800" [4]=> string(6) "175820" [5]=> string(6) "234823" [6]=> string(6) "253080" [7]=> string(6) "256680" [8]=> string(6) "258760" [9]=> string(6) "258840" [10]=> string(6) "259560" [11]=> string(6) "258480" [12]=> string(6) "258550" [13]=> string(6) "258660" [14]=> string(6) "258480" [15]=> string(6) "258300" [16]=> string(6) "256140" [17]=> string(6) "257770" [18]=> string(6) "255960" [19]=> string(6) "255780" [20]=> string(6) "252520" [21]=> string(6) "253980" [22]=> string(6) "252540" [23]=> string(6) "250560" [24]=> string(6) "245700" [25]=> string(6) "253080" [26]=> string(6) "248580" [27]=> string(6) "248860" [28]=> string(6) "249660" [29]=> string(6) "246780" [30]=> string(4) "2150" [31]=> string(5) "63800" [32]=> string(6) "175420" [33]=> string(6) "234843" [34]=> string(6) "253080" [35]=> string(4) "2110" [36]=> string(5) "63800" [37]=> string(6) "175820" [38]=> string(6) "234823" [39]=> string(6) "252180" [40]=> string(6) "256680" } }
```

`$flock` is equal to the assigned variable to the array.
`$numFlocks` is equal to an array of 1,2,3

```
<table>
 {section name=stand loop=$numFlocks}       

    <tr>
       {foreach from=$numFlocks item=columns}
          <td>{$flock[stand].$columns}</td>
       {/foreach}
   </tr>
 {/section}

</table>
```

The above produces a table like the below.

63800       175820      234823

2160        63800       175820

Array       2160        63800

This is far off what I'm looking for. I'm obviously getting my three columns but I don't get why I'm only getting three rows and the values are all wrong.

Below is my PHP code which creates the above array $flock.

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $numFlocksTot; $x++) {

    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT Amount_eggs FROM farm_weekly WHERE Flock_id = '" . $x . "' AND Client_id = '" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'", $connection) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error()); 

    while ($line1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
    {
        $val[] = $line1["Amount_eggs"]; 
    }

    $flock[] = array_merge($flock, $val); 
}
```

I've fixed my PHP,

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $numFlocksTot; $x++) {

$Q = "SELECT units FROM farm_weekly WHERE Flock_id = '" . $x . "' AND Client_id = '" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'";

$result1 = mysql_query($Q, $connection) or die("Query failed : " .      mysql_error()); 

while ($line1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
    $val = $line1["units"];
    array_push($flock, $val); 
}

    array_push($result, $flock); 
    unset($flock);
    $flock[] = array();
}
```

VAR_EXPORT spits out:

```
   array ( 0 => array ( ), 1 => array ( 0 => array ( ), 1 => '2160', 2 => '63800', 3 => '175820', 4 => '234823', 5 => '253080', 6 => '256680', 7 => '258760', 8 => '258840', 9 => '259560', 10 => '258480', 11 => '258550', 12 => '258660', 13 => '258480', 14 => '258300', 15 => '256140', 16 => '257770', 17 => '255960', 18 => '255780', 19 => '252520', 20 => '253980', 21 => '252540', 22 => '250560', 23 => '245700', 24 => '253080', 25 => '248580', 26 => '248860', 27 => '249660', 28 => '246780', ), 2 => array ( 0 => array ( ), 1 => '2150', 2 => '63800', 3 => '175420', 4 => '234843', 5 => '253080', ), 3 => array ( 0 => array ( ), 1 => '2110', 2 => '63800', 3 => '175820', 4 => '234823', 5 => '252180', 6 => '256680', ), )
```

However my SMART table is still causing problems:

```
 <tr>
  {foreach from=$numFlocks item=columns}
    {section loop=$flock name=unit}
        <td>{$flock[unit].$columns}</td>
    {/section}
  {/foreach}
 </tr>
```

The above attempt only gives me one row with 10 columns. First column is blank, then the first three entries for each inner array but then stops.

Comment: Your array looks quite strange after edit

Comment: Yes it does, thank you. I've added my PHP code that creates the array to give more detail.

Comment: The array would be easier to debug if you use `var_export` instead.

Comment: A couple other things to note. Running queries inside a loop is bad practice, it would be better to query all at once. Second, MySQL Original is deprecated and you might as well use MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: @PaulRedmond I've added the exported data to the question..

Comment: @Daenu I've fixed my array I believe..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMART/HTML

```
<th>Blank</th>
  {foreach from=$numFlocks item=foo}
<th>Flock {$foo}</th>
  {/foreach}
</tr>

{section loop=$flock[1] name=unit}
  <tr {if $smarty.section.unit.first}style="display:none"{/if}>
{foreach from=$flock item=foo}
    <td>{$foo[unit]}</td>
{/foreach}
  </tr>
{/section}
```

PHP CODE

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $numFlocksTot; $x++) {

 $Q = "SELECT Amount_eggs FROM farm_weekly WHERE Flock_id = '" . $x . "' AND Client_id = '" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'";

 $result1 = mysql_query($Q, $connection) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error()); 

while ($line1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
    $val = $line1["Amount_eggs"];
    array_push($flock, $val); 
}

array_push($result, $flock); 
unset($flock);
$flock[] = array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{$flock[stand].$columns}
```

At first sight, the `$columns` variable is used wrong.
You are using it as a field name, but the values that `$columns` contains can also be arrays, and do not necessarily correspond with actual field names.

Comment: Any further comments or suggestions? Does the array look okay in order to achieve what I want?

Comment: the array itself is just what it is.
I do not know the background of the data, what it represents, what is the (possible) logic behind it. I can give you an example for just this data set, but that might not help you.

Comment: The data above describes different years in this case three years. Every value within the year equals units per week. Basically I want to show a table where the columns are years and rows are weeks and all the cells show the units of that week. The weeks all start on the same week but may not finish the same. So some columns may have more rows than others.